# not able to identify the button action on swift code for react-native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, button

I am working on a react-native app that includes an iOS native module containing a video player and some buttons. However, I am unable to trigger the click event on the buttons in my Swift code. I added a debugger to the buttonAction method in my Swift code, but it did not get activated after clicking on the button. I shared my Swift code with a developer who said it appears to be fine, so the issue does not seem to be on the Swift side. Can anyone suggest what might be causing the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: It will be hard for us to find out the issue without some code you have worked on, so please edit your question per the stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.